# Desire2Learn LTI Link Importing

Tags: desire2learn, lti

I'm working on an integration with Desire2Learn.

I/We've been able to import course structure successfully, and when we add activity LTI links directly (manually), the functionality is great at first glance (enrollments happen from D2L to our content provider application, grades are passed from our content provider application back to D2L, etc).

As far as I understand from searching around the internet and our organization's "tribal knowledge" D2L does NOT support LTI links in their common cartridge imports.  Is this still correct?

Researching workarounds to this, I came across the following: [Can a desire2learn remote plugin be used to insert a custom external learning tool link into a course module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284305/can-a-desire2learn-remote-plugin-be-used-to-insert-a-custom-external-learning-to)   - the first answer seems to indicate that this functionality was being addressed through the Valence API as of Spring 2013.  However, I haven't been able to find confirmation of that anywhere in the 10.2 release documentation I've found.  Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Learning Framework APIs offer functionality to create LTI links that can be inserted into content: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/lti.html

We have a sample that demonstrates how to do this, which is introduced on the Valence Developer Blog: http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/10/21/so-you-want-to-extend-your-lms-part-2-remote-plugins/

If those APIs don't quite meet your use case, or if you have questions about the sample, come over to the ValenceUsers forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/valenceusers) to let D2L staff and the rest of the Valence Community know.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Importing LTI links was added with the March Continuous Delivery release (10.4.9).

[March 2015 Release Notes](https://community.brightspace.com/resources/documentation/2015_03_release_notes/201503d2lbrightspaceplatformreleasenotes)